# Porque no me guarda los datos mysql mediante php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

código html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insertarp.php">
<b> Codigo Producto</b>
<input type=text name="codigop" > <br><br>
<b> Nombre Producto </b>
<input type=text name="nombrep" > <br><br>
<b> Valor Producto</b>
<input type=text name="valorp" > <br><br>
<input type=submit value="Insertar" ><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CÓDIGO PHP

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root','','almacen');

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo"Lo sentimos, este sitio web esta experimentando problemas <br>";
    echo"ERROR: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a:<br>";
    echo "Errno:  ". $mysqli->connect_errno . "<br>";
    exit;
}
else {
    $codigop=$_POST['codigop'];
    $nombrep=$_POST['nombrep'];
    $valorp=$_POST['valorp'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO producto VALUES ('".$codigop."', '".$nombrep."','".$valorp."')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo "Los datos fueron ingresados correctamente <br> <br>";

}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[image: aqui estan mis dos tablas]

Comment: Te da algun error?

Comment: recibis algun error? algo? las variables que recibis por post estan correctas? tienen contenido? Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No, no muestra ningun error, ya verifique las variables muchas veces. en esta tabla ni siquiera ha recibido datos, en otra que realice me tomo dos datos pero ya no me toma mas.

Comment: pues no veo ningun error en tu codigo ya lo verifique , asegurate de que es el nombre de la tabla correcto o si no intenta hacer tu codigo de otra manera

Comment: Gracias, inetentare otro rato. Si no tocara de otra manera.

Comment: Si tu archivo php se llama "insertarp.php", no debería haber ningún error, pero sino quizá te sobra una "p".

Comment: si, asi se llama mi archivo, no se que sera.

Answer (score 1):

intenta recoje el valor de tus inputs antes que todo, intenta hacerlo asi

```
  <?php

    $codigop=$_POST['codigop'];
    $nombrep=$_POST['nombrep'];
    $valorp=$_POST['valorp'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root','','almacen');

    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo"Lo sentimos, este sitio web esta experimentando problemas <br>";
        echo"ERROR: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a:<br>";
        echo "Errno:  ". $mysqli->connect_errno . "<br>";
        exit;
    }
    else {
       //este codigo es una pesima practica y vulnerable a ataques sql
        $sql = "INSERT INTO producto VALUES ('".$codigop."', '".$nombrep."','".$valorp."')";
 //intenta hacer un insert con sus correspondientes campos

 $sql = "INSERT INTO producto (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ('".$codigop."', '".$nombrep."','".$valorp."')";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        echo "Los datos fueron ingresados correctamente <br> <br>";

    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: No sabia, apenas estoy aprendiendo, voy a intentar como me dices. gracias

Comment: No, tampoco de la manera que me dices. ni idea que podria ser jajajaja

Comment: entonces verifica bien que eso son los nombres correctos de los campos por que el codigo no tiene ningun error de sintaxis cualquier letricas que te comas ya sea en los campos o en el archivp php no te va a funcionar,necesitas prohevernos mas informacion  si puedes edita el codigo y sube una foto de tu tabla de la base de datos

Comment: ya subi la imagen del codigo de las dos tablas.

Comment: no entiendo bien el diseño de tu tabla por que no pones los campos varchar y porque la longitud del campo "codigop" es de 5 y no haces una condicion en ese input de que el maximo es de 5

Comment: Asi es como me han enseñado en donde estudio, y pues asi ha funcionado antes, asi que no sabria hacer la condicion en el input, y el "char" en vez de "varchar" por memoria al procesar. vuelvo a indicar, es como me han enseñado, no se si habran mejores formas al momento de crear la sintaxys

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste @JulianGil?

Comment: NO, ya no se que mas intentar